# Pycharm/Pytorch - 'tensor' is not callable

Tags: pycharm, pytorch, tensor

When creating a pytorch (1.0) tensor :

```
import torch
W = torch.tensor(([1.0]))
```

Pycharm (2018.3.1) gives me the following warning :

```
'tensor' is not callable less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection highlights attempts to call objects which are not callable, like, for example, tuples
```

My code works fine (tensor() is callable) but I'd like to understand and get rid of this warning.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyCharm, but why do you use double brackets? If you want to hand over a tuple: Not sure about python2, but for python3 `([1.0])` does not return a tuple. For a tuple you need to add a comma like `([1.0],)`.

Comment: Same warning/highlight with single brackets : W = torch.tensor([1.0])

Comment: Would you please add your PyTorch version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This has been a known issue to them](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/v0-4-pycharm-unknown-inspections-unexpected-argument-not-callable-etc/17810) . The moderator replied with:

> We will fix this in the next release. It’s being tracked at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7318

However, the reported issue was on PyTorch `v0.4.1`